# Continuous functions defined on $[a, b]$ with values in a non-locally convex topological vector space that are not integrable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, topological-vector-spaces

I have come across this fact in some paper but I don't remember where exactly: it  says that continuous functions defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$ in the set $\Bbb{R}$ of real numbers with values in a non-locally convex topological vector space may fail to be integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Then my question here is:

**Question:**
Are there some published examples of such functions? Or, are there examples of continuous functions defined on $[a, b]$ that are not integrable?

Comment: It is a very standard result that a real continuous function on a finite interval is both Riemann and Lebesgue integrable, whether you are concerned with the antiderivative or the definite integral.  It's hard to guess what it might mean to take values in a non-locally convex TVS.

Comment: @hardmath That is true for functions taking real values, but that's not what the question asks.

Comment: @N.S.  So is there a definition of what integration over a path in a non-locally convex TVS means? My point is that a trivial reason for the function not to be integrable is that integration is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the space $\ell_p$ for $p = 1/4$. This space equipped with distance $\rho(x, y) = \|x - y\|^p$ is not locally convex complete metrizable topological vector space. Denote $e_n$ the vectors of the canonical basis of $\ell_p$, that is $e_1 = (1, 0, 0, ...)$, $e_2 = (0, 1, 0, 0, ...)$, etc. Let $\Delta_n = [2/(2n+1), 1/n]$. The intervals $\Delta_n$ are mutually disjoint and tend to 0. Now define the required function $f: [0, 1] \to \ell_p$ as follows: on every $\Delta_n$ the function $f$ takes the constant value $e_n/n$; between two neighboring intervals $\Delta_n$, $\Delta_{n+1}$ define $f$ by means of linear interpolation (in order to make it continuous), and put $f(0) = 0$.